# Crate dynamic sub-tables using IF, COUNTIF, INDEX, SMALL

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

I am very much struggling with creating dynamic sub-tables from a master.

I want to drive through the content of each row (Rows: A-N) to seven further worksheets determined by the "Practice" that each Client belongs to (there are 7 Practices; Manufacturing, Supply Chain, HR & Board, etc..).

I had been using the code (below) in the cell A4 of each individual worksheet. Cells B1 give the name of the Practice and Cell D1 gives the total number of entries for each practice.

`=IF(ROWS(A$4:A4)>$E$1,"",INDEX(MASTER!A$2:A$300,SMALL(IF(Table1[Practice]=$B$1,ROW(Table1[Practice])-ROW(MASTER!$C$2)+1),ROWS(A$4:A4))))`

[Master Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWl7J.jpg)

[One of Practice Worksheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PerJ6.jpg)

I have also been using [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/embed/tqCEY5YMyqw) as a framework.

Any help would be much appreciated as I'm now completely stuck! The formula will not pick out the correct “Practice” nor will it continue the drill-through method on other worksheets!

Comment: @TotsieMae: (1) Thank you for your effort to improve this question. Please note that I approved your suggested edit, and then I made further changes. (2) When you convert a link-to-an-image to an image, please do it the way I have done it. That way, a reader can click on an image in a post and go directly to the full-size image. (3) We prefer that you not use text formatting so liberally for names. But I might have left that part of your edit alone if you have done it consistently. As it is, you used **bold**, *italics* and `code formatting` for things that should have been formatted the same.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using a pivot table?

Comment: @sambr: Where do I begin? (1) Please don’t post images of text. We prefer that worksheet data be uploaded ***as text***, so (1a) they can be copied and pasted, and (1b) blind people can read them. (2) If you *must* upload images, try to keep them to a maximum width of 600 to 700 pixels. Your images are 2457 and 2564 pixels wide. Therefore, they have to be compressed (shrunken) to fit the page, and this makes them hard to read. This is especially bad in your case because your images have so much empty space in them — the second one even has blank space at the top, bottom, and sides.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  If you *must* upload of images of spreadsheets, please shrink the columns so they’re only as wide as their contents.  (3) But ***don’t*** crop off the row numbers and column headers.  Thank you for showing us the formula you are working with, but it’s hard to understand if we don’t know which columns are `A`, `C` and `E`.  Also, I don’t know where you *put* that formula, so that also makes it hard to understand.  (4) Overall, your question is very hard to understand.  The thing I find most troubling is that you show us an example table … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  that applies to “Board & HR” values under “Practice” in the “Master” worksheet — but there are no “Board & HR” values under “Practice” in the “Master” worksheet.  But also, I basically am not sure I understand what you are asking.  Do you want seven new worksheets to be created, with a table on each one, based on the data in the “Master” sheet?  Or only three, because there are only three distinct values in the “Practice” column?  I’m not sure what your second image is supposed to illustrate, other than that it is a sheet/table that has “Board & HR” in a cell … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  and has a column named “Practice”.  Where are you trying to use your formula?  What do you expect it to do?  Providing the link to the YouTube video is good, but don’t expect us to go and look at it — we expect to be able to understand your question ***by reading your question***.  (5) Worksheet functions can’t change the workbook.  If you want the workbook to change (e.g., new sheets to be created), worksheet functions alone won’t do it.   It might be possible with VBA.   But you might be better off switching to a different tool, like a database tool.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … And if you don’t want the workbook to change, you need to make your question a lot clearer. (Do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete. (PS) Why do you say that your question is about `COUNTIF` (you mention it in the title, and you used the [countif] tag) when you don’t mention `COUNTIF` in the question?

Comment: @Scott Thank you for your response. First time poster and I missed some of the etiquette, I can understand how frustrating it is. I have tried to streamline my question. Hopefully this will help you in helping me. All the best, Sam.